# Golang AWS CDK autoscaling undefined types

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am using the AWS CDK for golang and am getting the following undefined errors:

```
cd cdk && cdk deploy
# command-line-arguments
./ecs-run-task.go:54:22: undefined: autoscaling
./ecs-run-task.go:54:54: undefined: this
./ecs-run-task.go:54:81: undefined: autoScalingGroupProps
./ecs-run-task.go:62:69: undefined: cpuUtilizationScalingProps
./ecs-run-task.go:66:72: undefined: cpuUtilizationScalingProps
./ecs-run-task.go:70:22: undefined: ecs
./ecs-run-task.go:70:49: undefined: this
./ecs-run-task.go:70:92: undefined: asgCapacityProviderProps
./ecs-run-task.go:73:9: cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider undefined (type awsecs.Cluster has no field or method addAsgCapacityProvider, but does have AddAsgCapacityProvider)
./ecs-run-task.go:114:72: cannot refer to unexported name awsecs.taskDefinitionProps
./ecs-run-task.go:73:9: too many errors
```

I have these packages imported:

```
"strings"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsec2"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsecs"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsiam"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awslambda"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awslambdaeventsources"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awslambdago"
"github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awss3"
"github.com/aws/constructs-go/constructs/v3"
"github.com/aws/jsii-runtime-go"
```

Here is the source code where I am trying to create and attach an auto scaling group:

```
// Create the cluster.
cluster := awsecs.NewCluster(stack, jsii.String("ecsCluster"), &awsecs.ClusterProps{
    Vpc: vpc,
    EnableFargateCapacityProviders: newTrue(),
})

//Creating auto scaling group to attach to cluster
autoScalingGroup := autoscaling.NewAutoScalingGroup(this, jsii.String("ASG"), &autoScalingGroupProps{
    vpc: vpc,
    instanceType: ec2.NewInstanceType(jsii.String("t2.micro")),
    machineImage: ecs.ecsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
    minCapacity: jsii.Number(0),
    maxCapacity: jsii.Number(100),
})

autoScalingGroup.scaleOnCpuUtilization(jsii.String("CpuScaling"), &cpuUtilizationScalingProps{
    targetUtilizationPercent: jsii.Number(90),
})

autoScalingGroup.scaleOnCpuUtilization(jsii.String("MemoryScaling"), &cpuUtilizationScalingProps{
    targetUtilizationPercent: jsii.Number(90),
})

capacityProvider := ecs.NewAsgCapacityProvider(this, jsii.String("AsgCapacityProvider"), &asgCapacityProviderProps{
    autoScalingGroup: autoScalingGroup,
})
cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider)
```

Does anyone know what I need to import or do to be able to access features such as autoscaling. The cdk documentation on AWS and here https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2/awsautoscaling#section-readme show example of all these tools with no issues but I havent had any luck and tried multiple imports from cdk v2 and elsewhere.

Comment: @BellinghamBoss Thanks for getting back and I've added it now -  i'll remember to add source for any future questions

Comment: Import "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsautoscaling".  Replace text `autoScalingGroupProps` with `awsautoscaling.AutoScalingGroupProps`,  replace text `autoscaling` with `awsautoscaling`,  replace text `cpuUtilizationScalingProps` with `awsautoscaling.CpuUtilizationScalingProps`, fix line 73 per the error message.  There are more typos, but this should get you get started.

Comment: @BellinghamBoss Thank you that helped me fix most of the issues. I have been looking for these two errors in cdk guide `./ecs-run-task.go:55:57: undefined: this
                                                                                                                                  ./ecs-run-task.go:58:41: awsecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2 undefined (type awsecs.EcsOptimizedImage has no method amazonLinux2)` The go cdk guide states that there is a method amazonLinux2 and the doc also refers to this in multiple functions. Sorry for all the questions and thanks again

Comment: It's not clear where `this` is coming from.  The [acsecs.EcsOptimizedImage documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsecs#EcsOptimizedImage) does not list the method amazonLinux2.  Even if there is a method with that name, you cannot call it because the method is not exported.

Comment: Thanks again. I’ll try omitting or looking for alternatives for these

Comment: `this` is used as the type of an anonymous function argument.   You probably intended to use `this` as the name of the argument and accidentally omitted the type for that argument.

Comment: Thanks yes I replaced with stack and it accepted it, I was looking to closely at the go docs without thinking about what I was writing when i used this. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

package to import "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsapplicationautoscaling"

```
// AutoScaling based on memory and cpu usage
        scalabletargetPub := pubService.AutoScaleTaskCount(&awsapplicationautoscaling.EnableScalingProps{
            MinCapacity: &apps.ApplicationVpc.ECS.AppMktNodeCountMin,
            MaxCapacity: &apps.ApplicationVpc.ECS.AppMktNodeCountMax,
        })

        scalabletargetPub.ScaleOnMemoryUtilization(jsii.String("Memory_threshold"), &ecs.MemoryUtilizationScalingProps{
            TargetUtilizationPercent: &apps.ApplicationVpc.ECS.AppMemoryUtilizationThresholdPercent,
        })
        scalabletargetPub.ScaleOnCpuUtilization(jsii.String("Cpu_threshold"), &ecs.CpuUtilizationScalingProps{
            TargetUtilizationPercent: &apps.ApplicationVpc.ECS.AppCPUUtilizationThresholdPercent,
        })
```